# Most vexing parse C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm confused about `Y y {X{}};` what exactly this line does and what is its connection to the most vexing parse. A brief explanation is appreciated:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
    X() { std::cout << "X"; }
};
struct Y {
    Y(const X &x) { std::cout << "Y"; }
    void f() { std::cout << "f"; }
};
int main() {
    Y y { X{} };
    y.f();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> what exactly this line does

It creates a temporary `X`, value-initialising it by calling the default constructor, and then uses that to initialise a `Y` variable, calling the `const X&` conversion constructor.

> where is connection to Most vexing parse

If you were to try to write this using old-school initialisation syntax

```
Y y (X());
```

then the so-called "most vexing parse" would interpret this as a function, rather than a variable, declaration: a function called `y`, with return type `Y` and a single parameter, whose type is a (pointer to a) function returning `X`.

You could add extra parentheses, so that it can't be interpreted as a function declaration:

```
Y y ((X()));
```

or, since C++11, you can use brace-initialisation as your example does.

Comment: `sometype a(())` this giving `Error: Expected Expression` (inside the inner bracket) on C++14. `sometype`  is a class.

Answer (score 3):

```
Y y { X{} };
```

This is perfect and creates an object `y` passing a temporary object of type `X` to the constructor. There is NO vexing parse (most or otherwise). In fact, the construction using `{}` was introduced to solve the issue of vexing parse in many cases, such as these:

```
 Y y1();
 Y y2(X());
```

Both belongs to (most) vexing parse because of which both declares functions, instead of objects.

However, if you use curly braces called *brace-initialization*:

```
 Y y1{};
 Y y2{ X{} }; //as you've done yourself
```

then both declares objects, not functions, as expected.

Comment: `Y y2(X())`  and `Y y2(X x1)` both interpreted as function but `A a1(2)` is interpreted as declaration where `Class A` contains `1-arg constructor` which takes int type argument. isn't these both things contradictory ?

Comment: Also `Y y2(X{})` interpreted as variable declaration. I am not getting this concept clearly.

Comment: @AbhishekMane: Please read more about it. There are enough contents out there. I'm sure you'll understand if you read more. A a very short explanation for **why `A a(int())` is treated as function, but `A a(0)` is not**... is : if a syntax _can_ be interpreted as functions and objects _both_, then the spec says it shall be interpreted as functions by a conforming compiler.