# c++ compiler thinks vector initialization is a function call

Tags: c++

I have the following two lines of code:

```
vector<int> temp(istream_iterator<int>(cin), 
                 istream_iterator<int>());

copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Which is supposed to read from stdin into a vector containing int and prints it to stdout.

But I get the following error:

```
request for member ‘begin’ in ‘temp’, which is of non-class type ‘std::vector<int>(std::istream_iterator<int>, std::istream_iterator<int> (*)())’
 copy(temp.begin(), temp.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Which I suspect I get is because the vector initialization looks suspiciously like a function prototype. How do I fix this?

Comment: It's not saying function call, it's saying function declaration.

Comment: `istream_iterator<int>(cin)` ===> `(istream_iterator<int>(cin))`, or just use universal initialization. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094774/most-vexing-parse-c11) for examples of both techniques.

Comment: More on most vexing parse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work

Comment: Use `vector<int> temp(istream_iterator<int>{cin}, 
                 istream_iterator<int>{});`.